# Correlation of vector signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the correlation of a vector (Mono-signal) in Matlab. So far I know, this should be give a correlation matrix, but in Matlab I don't find the function that gives me a matrix. Xcorr() gives a vector. So if someone know I would appreciate it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the `corrcoef` function:

> ```
> corrcoef(rand(10,1),rand(10,1))
>
> ans =
>
>   1.0000   -0.2110
>
>  -0.2110    1.0000
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For a time series, the correlation is defined as a vector.

Maybe you want something like:

A*(A.')

Where A is a column vector.